# why the python3 did not hit breakpoint in schedule task in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using this code to capture Python 3 exception in PyCharm `PyCharm 2022.1 (Professional Edition)`, this is my code look like:

```
@staticmethod
def parse_single(entry, source):
    try:
        pub_time = entry.get("published", "None")
        guid = entry.get("id", "")
        title = entry.get("title", "")
        author = entry.get("author", "")
        link = entry.get("link", "")
        article_content = entry.get("content", "")
        if article_content is None or len(article_content) == 0:
            article_content = entry.get("summary_detail", "")
            if article_content is None or len(article_content) == 0:
                return
            content = article_content.value
            save_single(guid, pub_time, title, author, content, source, link)
        else:
            content = article_content[0].get("value", "")
            save_single(guid, pub_time, title, author, content, source, link)
    except BaseException as e:
        logger.error("save single rss article data error,rss:" + source.sub_url, e)
```

I make a breakpoint in the line:

```
logger.error("save single rss article data error,rss:" + source.sub_url, e)
```

but when I debug this code, the breakpoint did not trigger and stop in this line. The breakpoint setting to capture `Any Exception` in PyCharm. why this happen? what should I to do make it stop in breakpoint in PyCharm? Am I missing something? This is the log output:

```
  File "/home/dolphin/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/212.5457.59/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2164, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/dolphin/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/212.5457.59/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1476, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "/home/dolphin/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/212.5457.59/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/dolphin/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/212.5457.59/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/tests/cruise/rss_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    rss_parse.feeder_parse(rss, "1", "ddd")
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/blog/rss/RssParser.py", line 49, in feeder_parse
    RssParser.parse_single(entry, source)
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/blog/rss/RssParser.py", line 97, in parse_single
    logger.error("save single rss article data error,rss:" + source.sub_url, e)
Message: 'save single rss article data error,rss:https://incidentdatabase.ai/rss.xml'
Arguments: (IndexError('list index out of range'),)
```

By the way, when I set a breakpoint in the main function, it works. But when I set the breakpoint in schedule task function, it could not trigger the breakpoint. The schedule code look like this:

```
# coding=utf-8

import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from dolphin.biz.dict.fetch_centence import FetchSentence
from dolphin.biz.music.fetch_music import FetchMusic
from dolphin.biz.rss_entry import RssEntry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    rss = RssEntry()
    # sentence_fetcher = FetchSentence()
    # music_download_url_fetcher = FetchMusic()
    #
    #
    scheduler.add_job(rss.rss_sub, 'cron', args=['1'], minute='*/1', max_instances=1)
    scheduler.add_job(rss.rss_sub, 'cron', args=['2'], minute='*/1', max_instances=1)
    scheduler.add_job(rss.rss_sub, 'cron', args=['3'], minute='*/1', max_instances=1)
    # scheduler.add_job(sentence_fetcher.fetch, 'cron', args=[], second='*/6', max_instances=1)
    # scheduler.add_job(music_download_url_fetcher.fetch_music_url, 'cron', args=[], minute='*/5', max_instances=1)
    scheduler.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(20)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

when I set the breakpoint in `rss_sub` function, it would not work. The `parse_single` function was nested in the `rss_sub` function.

Comment: Since you are handling the current exception, do you actually have an (new) exception on the line where your breakpoint is?

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? `article_content[0]`?

Comment: Ok, so python 3 IS hitting your exception, right? It's printing your message. So the problem isn't that the exception isn't being hit, it's that PyCharm isn't stopping. If you put your breakpoint before the exception, does it stop then? I don't see any problems with anything that is in your question, so it seems to me the problem is something that's not shown. Are you familiar with using the debugger? Can you get the debugger working at all?

Comment: N, the exception was throwed from nested invoke method. @nanotek

Comment: The point will stop in the PyCharm debugger in other location, only in this line could not stop, I want to stop in this line to see the variable, but it could not stopped. @nanotek

Comment: Any idea how nested it is? Could you try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`. Try putting a breakpoint at `pub_time = ...` and see if that is caught. Also, put a breakpoint at the line `content = article_content[0]...` If the error is in the above code, I'm guessing that's where it would be given the error is `IndexError`